# set-car! and let in scheme language

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, mit-scheme

I am little bit confused by the result of this example:

```
(define mk-q
  (lambda ()
    (let ([l '(x)])
      (cons l l))))


(define q (mk-q))

q
=> ((x) x)

(set-car! (cdr q) 'y)
=> ((y) y)
```

I am wondering why both `x` atoms have been replaced by `set-car!` procedure (my first guess for what the result would be was `((x) y)`)?

For example:

```
(define mk-q2
  (lambda ()
    (let ([l '(x)])
      (cons l (cons l l)))))

(define q2 (mk-q2))
(set-car! (cdr q2) 'y)
=> ((x) y x) which fits my understanding of set-car!
```

Why are both `x`s in the first example replaced?

Comment: Because a cons cell is essentially two pointers to values. When you write `(cons l l)` you create two pointers to the same object. When you change the object, both entries still point to the same object.

Comment: I initially misread this as set-carl, which was amusing in an aqua teen hunger force sort of way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, you have something equivalent to this:

```
(define cell (cons 'x null))
(define q (cons cell cell))
```

As you can see, there's only *one* `cons` cell with `x` at the `car` position, that is being shared in two different parts of the resulting list structure. When you execute `(set-car! (cdr q) 'y)` the `x` in the single cell gets replaced by `y` in all the parts where it's being shared. Remembering that both `(cons 'x null)` cells are really the same, we're going from this:

```
(cons (cons 'x null) (cons 'x null))
; '((x) x)
```

to this:

```
(cons (cons 'y null) (cons 'y null))
; '((y) y)
```

For the second example the same considerations apply (all three `(cons 'x null)` cells are actually the same one being shared), but you're replacing a whole `cons` cell, so basically we're going from this:

```
(cons (cons 'x null) (cons (cons 'x null) (cons 'x null)))
; '((x) (x) x)
```

to this:

```
(cons (cons 'x null) (cons 'y (cons 'x null)))
; '((x) y x)
```

To prove my point that both of the examples in the question demonstrate the same situation, execute this expressions:

```
(define q2 (mk-q2))
(set-car! (cadr q2) 'y) ; notice the extra `a`
q2
=> '((y) (y) y)
```